# how do we read data from two columns in a csv/xls file into 2 variables and use them for the program using python

Tags: python, excel, csv

How do we read data from two columns in a csv/xls file into 2 variables to use them for a later part of the program using Python?

Typically I want the data  to be picked from an excel file for the variables `a` & `b` below and give me the ratio of the variables of all the rows in the two columns:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def similar(a, b):
    return SequenceMatcher(None,a ,b).ratio()
```

Comment: If they're ordered you can create 2 lists, one containing everything in a, and another containing everything in b. Then since they're ordered you can just do set, and divide OR you can use a lambda function. Code solutions of these are provided pretty widely in the stackoverflow community.

Comment: I searched a lot based on your recommendation but could not find a solution specific to min...plz advise

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas package to do it:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', usecols = ['a','b'])
```

It reads columns with headers "a" and "b" from your file and puts them into a dataframe df. For more options see [read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv). (And there is also a similar `read_xls` function.)

Then you can access the df columns with `df['a']` or `df.a`, for example:

```
SequenceMatcher(None, df['a'], df['b']).ratio()
```